# Copy files from unspecified number subdirectories

Tags: command-line, copy

I have a directory tree as follows

```
/
--/Directory1
--/Directory2
-----/SubDir1
-----/SubDir2
```

Each of these has a file with a .mp4 extension I am looking for, and want to move to another folder.
I have tried:

`cp -rv ./*/*.mp4 ~/foo`

However that only gets files from Directory1 and Directory2, and if I just search for *.mp4 I only search the root directory.

I would like to let you know, I'm not actually doing this in my root directory, this is just an example, please no condescending comments unless I've actually missed something very basic.

Comment: Change the /home to .  and /backup/ in the command in this example link and it will search every directory beneath the current one for the files to move, changing the .zip to .mp4 of course to. https://www.howtogeek.com/168164/move-files-into-one-directory-in-linux-with-find/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a shell that supports recursive globbing, you can enable that ex.

```
shopt -s globstar        # bash
```

then use

```
cp -v ./**/*.mp4 ~/foo
```

(`-r` is not appropriate here, assuming that the `*.mp4` are *regular files*). Alternatively, use `find` for the recursive descent:

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec cp -vt ~/foo {} +
```

The `globstar` method will fail if the number of matches is sufficiently large; the `find` method should work regardless.